# Can we use $lookup to have multiple localFields referencing multiple foreignFields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Can we join two collections in MongoDB with multiple conditions something like below example ?

Example

```
db.Person.aggregate([
    { $lookup : {
        from: "Person",           
        localField: "_id",           
        localField:  “businessGroup",       
        foreignField:  “personId",  
        foreignField:  “businessGroupCode",         
        as: "person"      
    } }
])
```

Thanks

More details about my query

I have 3 collections col1, col2, col3.  I need to join these collections so that my output should have

ScenarioName from Col1 and runId from Col2 and latest results from col3(i.e col2.runId = col3.runId)

```
**testscenario:**


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f41cb9319ed34079df8a2d"),
    "environment" : "STAGE",
    "component" : "test1",
    "scenarioName" : "Jira-1234",
    "testClass" : "com.test.Test1",

}

**componentrunId:**

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57fc5f56e40a93f2e0ae953c"),
    "componentName" : "test1",
    "runId" : 415
}

**testResults :**

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5914d0019385b71384e01b2e"),
    "_class" : "com.test.TestResults",
    "testScenarioId" : ObjectId("5900fbc1aa42d292ecf596ab"),
    "runId" : 608,
    "runDate" : ISODate("2017-05-11T20:56:19.226Z"),
    "status" : "inprogress",
    "retryCount" : 0.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5915b609637b4a42d362babb"),
    "_class" : "com.test.TestResults",
    "testScenarioId" : ObjectId("58a4b2028f67f440d08b9845"),
    "runId" : 607,
    "runDate" : ISODate("2017-05-12T13:18:01.305Z"),
    "status" : "passed"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5915b60c637b4a42d362babc"),
    "_class" : "com.test.TestResults",
    "testScenarioId" : ObjectId("57ffa1a67ae6ee5093b978cb"),
    "runId" : 606,
    "runDate" : ISODate("2017-05-12T13:18:04.106Z"),
    "status" : "passed"
}
```

Query i wrote

```
db.testScenario.aggregate(
[
{
    $lookup: 
    {
          from: "componentRunId",
          localField: "component",
          foreignField: "componentName",
          as: "testScenario_docs"
    }
},{
        $project:{
            "_id":"$_id",
            "scenarioName" :"$scenarioName",
            "runId" : "$testScenario_docs.runId",
            "componentName" :"$testScenario_docs.componentName"
        }
    },
     {
        $out:"varunTmp"
    }   

])

db.varunTmp.aggregate([
    {$lookup:
        {
           from: "testResults",
           localField: "_id",
            //localField: "runId",
           foreignField: "testScenarioId",
           // foreignField: "runId",
           as: "finalResult"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$finalResult"
    },

    {
        $project:{
            "runId" : "$finalResult.runId",
            "status" : "$finalResult.status",
            "scenarioName" :"$scenarioName"
        }
    }

])
```

Comment: No you cannot. Usage is exactly as stated on the [manual page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). Whilst you "can" do multiple `$lookup` stages ( which is the intended usage ), I suspect you are trying to do a "hierarchical graph". Not that it is not possible to "recurse" through objects like you probably want. You might want to look at [`$graphLookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/). But your question lacks detail of your structure and desired  goal to really tell.

Comment: Typo. Should say *"**Note** that it is not possible .."*

Comment: @NeilLunn : provided more detail to my question

Comment: It might be helpful to be less obtuse and provide collection names ( especially considering those are **vital** to a `$lookup` operation. But what is the query exactly? All results from "col1", joining it's "component" field to the "componentName" field of "col2", then joining on "runId" in "col2" to the same property in "col3"? That might be the clearer statement if true. You should also make it clear if "col1" to "col2" is a strict `1:1` relationship. It is at least clear that "col2" to "col3" is "one to many". Is this what you want? Again, would be much clearer with collection name in use

Comment: @NeilLunn : yes , you are right. i updated the collection name to be more clear .  "testscenario" and "componentRunId" is 1:1 and  testResults has 1 to many. query is returning results. it's retrieving all the results  from from "TestResults" collection instead of the one with latest run Id

Answer (score 1):

The usage you are looking for involves "multiple" [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operations in order to obtain the results, rather than trying to include all arguments in a single pipeline stage.

```js
db.testscenario.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "componentrunId",
    "localField": "component",
    "foreignField": "componentName",
    "as": "component"
  }},
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$component", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "testResults",
    "localField": "runId",
    "foreignField": "runId",
    "as": "tests"
  }}
])
```

From that base you can project whatever fields you want and/or do whatever manipulation you want, but the basic contents of all fields will be available.

Note that the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) here "may" result in documents being removed should the matching document from the `"componentrunId"` collection not be found. The result from [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) here would be an empty array, and you can get around this with the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` syntax as described in the documentation.

You also might well consider that your design pattern here is very "relational" yet being used in a "document database" where this is often not the best thing to do. As a "rule of thumb", if you are able to run this aggregation statement without running into the BSON limit, then you probably should have been "embedding" the data in the first place.